# Getting Runtime error while trying to open http:\\localhost\Reports in to the Reporting Server

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, reporting, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2015

I have installed MS CRM 2015 Server with SQL Server 2014. while working on to the Reporting Server whenever i am trying to open **http:\localhost\Reports** it gives me Runtime Error. But **http:\localhost\ReportServer** works well and it does not give me an error. I have tried to check the log files(**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles**) as well as the event viewer to trace the error but unfortunately I couldn't find anything. Can anyone help me with this issue? or is there any way to enable the logs to see why this error is occurring.

Please see the Runtime Error:

**Runtime Error**

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
</system.web>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the event viewer?

Comment: Dynamics CRM uses SQL's own Reporting Server. Are you sure /ReportServer doesn't have what you're looking for?

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky The CRM reports are working fine however i am trying to setup the email schedule. In order to sched

Comment: @AjayBisht what does the error message say after you change the Web.config?

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky The CRM reports are working fine however i am trying to schedule report and email subscription. In order to achieve this   whenever i am trying to open http://ReportServerName/Reports  its gives me the Runtime error. By the way http://ReportServerName/ReportServer works well. Please refer the given link to schedule report an demail subscription.                                                                                                   [link](http://www.powerobjects.com/2011/06/29/report-scheduling-and-email-subscription-in-crm-2011/)

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky I see no change after editing the Web.config. I have changed the following Web.config. I am not 100% sure if I am editing the correct one or not. 
1) C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer  
2) C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager. 
I have added the <customErrors mode="Off"/> to the respective web.config

Comment: @Jordi I do not see anything in the event viewer with respect to the reports server error.